# how to debug/test native module code efficiently in react native development

Tags: android, ios, react-native

my question is related to how experienced developers handle native module development efficiently in React Native.

I did not find any good articles about this topic besides generally how to create your first native module.

The reason I asked that is because in React Native, the JavaScript part can have HMR so the app can immediately reflect your changes. But for the native module part (iOS/android code), every time I change something, I have to rebuild and rerun the project, it can easily become a pain. I wonder if there are any existing tools to boost this dev process like HMR, or allows me to decouple and test the native module code specifically without constantly rebuilding the entire app.

Any suggestion from experienced developers is appreciated.